# SSRS calculating last day in February for previous year not returning 29 for leap years

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint list where each item has a date. I'm looking to filter that down to a given month in the previous year (so an input of February 2017 would return all items in February 2016). I have two parameters: @Month and @Year. When I use the following code, it works for all months/years except for February on leap years. Just using the code to filter on the month works for all dates, but when I add in the DateAdd year-1, it returns 28 for all Februaries.

```
DateAdd("YYYY",-1,DateAdd(“d”,-1,(DateAdd(“m”, 1, CDate(Parameters!Month.Value + " 1, " +str(Parameters!Year.Value))))))
```

If there is another to do this, I'd welcome that as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subtract the year first then the day.

```
=DateAdd("d",-1,DateAdd("YYYY",-1,(DateAdd("m", 1, CDate("2/1/2017")))))
```

Comment: That worked! Never thought about rearranging the order. Thanks so much!